# Today's Date in pandas with specific format - python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get today's data in pandas with the following int format:

```
2015,7,27
```

I am using it to get some data from a certain time frame:

```
sdate = date(2015,7,27)
edate = date(2015,7,31) #I would like not to hardcode it.
```

I tried:

```
 today = datetime.today().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

It outputs a string that I have to convert.

`<type 'str'>`

If I use the str it gives:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Is there a pythonic way to solve this?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: Your desired format is still unclear. Do you want a tuple of integers, or a comma-delimited string format? Also, when you say that your use of `datetime.today` "is wrong" what do you mean? How is the date wrong? Can you should an example?

Comment: Thank you for the questions @Mr.F. As far as I understand I need a tuple of integers separated by commas. I had a typo in `datetime.today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is not an int tuple, but you're calling a function `date` which requires 3 parameters of type int, the year, month and day. So to set the right end date you should call the date function and pass it the current date using:

```
edate = date(datetime.today().year,  datetime.today().month,  datetime.today().day)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It converts it to a tuple but I am getting `TypeError: an integer is required` when using it as a variable in `edate = date(today)`.

Comment: Try: edate = date(datetime.today().year,  datetime.today().month,  datetime.today().day)

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much! Why would not it work when I assign it to the variable `today`?

Comment: I just updated the answer, you were calling a function which asked for three different parameters of type int. Using the tuple you would pass on **one** bundle containing  three ints.